# htaccess redirect subdomain to root domain

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to redirect this subdomain:

```
http://abc.domain-name.com
```

to a folder on the root domain that uses the same name:

```
http://www.domain-name.com/abc
```

This way, if I try to access the following file:

```
http://abc.domain-name.com/folder/file.html
```

It will go to:

```
http://www.domain-name.com/abc/folder/file.html
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.yourdomain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www\.yourdomain\.com/subdomain/$1 [L]
```

(from http://systembash.com/content/simple-redirect-subdomain-to-a-directory/)

Answer (score 8):

You should consider about search engines and use [permanent redirect (301)](https://moz.com/learn/seo/redirection), also its best practice to use [NC flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_nc) at the end if second line to be matched in a case-insensitive manner.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.example\.com  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```