# redirect http/https subdomain (mail) to https main domain in .httaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https, subdomain, no-www

I know my question is asked many times but unfortunately I could't find my answer. Maybe because I don't put the .htaccess file in the correct place.
What I want is to redirect http://mail.example.com , https://mail.example.com to https://example.com.
I also wanted to redirect https://www.example.com , http://example.com, http://www.example.com to https://example.com. I did this job with adding below code in .htaccees file in public_html in cpanel and it works.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

I used below code from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13637933/htaccess-redirect-subdomain-to-root-domain/13637970) and put .htaccess file in mail folder. but when I type http://mail.example.com it redirects to https://mail.example.com and https://mail.example.com also doesn't go to http://example.com. Maybe the problem is with https.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mail\.mysit\.com  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Any help is appreciated.
p.s. My site is designed with joomla and there is no redirection in cpanel and joomla settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think everything is correct, and that 'it's only a matter of order:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mail\.example\.com  [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

In you main .htaccess file

Comment: Dear Croises, thank you. yes I used this code in .htaccess in Public_html and it works