# .htaccess: rewrite the adress in adress bar from subdomain to full path

Tags: .htaccess, web, subdomain

I want to achieve this:

If you visit the **subdomain** of a website, e.g.

```
project.website.com
```

I want it to be **replaced automatically** in the address bar to

```
https://website.com/project-directory
```

-> So the subdomain should directly lead to the full directory path **and also show that full path in the address bar**.

How do I achieve this using the .htaccess file? Or is another way better? Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this answer to a similar question:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.yourdomain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www\.yourdomain\.com/subdomain/$1 [L]
```

found it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13637970/17799753